# Apache not running correctly after upgrading to High Sierra

Tags: apache, high-sierra

I have an apache web server running on my mac.  Since upgrading to macOS High Sierra, if I connect to localhost or 10.0.0.7 in Safari (or any other web browser) I get the message "Safari can't open the page "localhost" because Safari can't connect to the server "localhost".

I can confirm apache is running.  If I run `apachectl configtest` I get "Syntax OK".

If I type `httpd -v` I get

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.28 (Unix)
Server built:   Oct 19 2017 09:26:34
```

I have tried restarting apache and this has no effect.  Does anyone have any idea how I can get it working?  All my web files are stored in /Library/WebServer/Documents.

Attached is a copy of my [httpd.conf](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0Oyt5NbxhRgjEFfDnLWmJu6mQ#httpd).

Comment: Is this version of Apache installed via homebrew, macports, or the like? The version I have is 2.4.27, which should be the same for everyone.

Comment: What happens if you try to ping both localhost and 10.0.0.7?

Comment: It is the version of apache installed from Homebrew.

Comment: If I ping 10.0.0.7 I get ping 10.0.0.7
PING 10.0.0.7 (10.0.0.7): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your `hosts` file, you should have entries in there for your localhost and local configuration. The `hosts` file is in `/etc`, so the best way to open it is by using Terminal and this (read-only) command:

```
open -a TextEdit /etc/hosts
```

You should see an one or all of these for localhost there like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost   
::1         localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

127.0.0.1 is your machine (aka localhost).

You can add other IP addresses from your local network to route domain names to a local development folder to the `hosts` file. For example, mine has custom entries from old projects like:

```
10.0.10.111     teambox.dongguk.ac.kr
```

To make changes to the `hosts` file, you'll need to use:

```
sudo open -a TextEdit /etc/hosts
```

Enter your user account password when prompted.

Here is a full article on making edits to your `hosts` file: [The Mac Hosts File: How to Modify /etc/hosts in OS X with TextEdit](http://osxdaily.com/2016/02/29/modify-hosts-mac-os-x-textedit/)